# Handling nested callbacks/promises with Mongoose

Tags: callback, promise

I am a beginner with Node.js and Mongoose. I spent an entire day trying to resolve an issue by scouring through SO, but I just could not find the right solution. Basically, I am using the retrieved values from one collection to query another. In order to do this, I am iterating through a loop of the previously retrieved results.

With the iteration, I am able to populate the results that I need. Unfortunately, the area where I am having an issue is that the response is being sent back before the required information is gathered in the array. I understand that this can be handled by callbacks/promises. I tried numerous ways, but I just haven't been successful with my attempts. I am now trying to make use of the [Q library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) to facilitate the callbacks. I'd really appreciate some insight. Here's a snippet of the portion where I'm currently stuck:

```
var length = Object.keys(purchasesArray).length;
var jsonArray = [];

var getProductDetails = function () {
var deferred = Q.defer();
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var property = Object.keys(purchasesArray)[i];
    if (purchasesArray.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        var productID = property;
        var productQuery = Product.find({asin: 
        productQuery.exec(function (err, productList) {
        jsonArray.push({"productName": productList[0].productName,
                           "quantity": purchasesArray[productID]});
        });
    }
}

return deferred.promise;
};

getProductDetails().then(function sendResponse() {
    console.log(jsonArray);
    response = {
        "message": "The action was successful",
        "products": jsonArray
    };
    res.send(response);
    return;
 }).fail(function (err) {
     console.log(err);
    })
 });
```

I am particularly able to send one of the two objects in the `jsonArray` array as the response is being sent after the first element.

**Update**

Thanks to *Roamer-1888* 's answer, I have been able to construct a valid JSON response without having to worry about the error of setting headers after sending a response.

Basically, in the `getProductDetails()` function, I am trying to retrieve product names from the Mongoose query while mapping the quantity for each of the items in `purchasesArray`. From the function, eventually, I would like to form the following response:

```
 response = {
     "message": "The action was successful",
     "products": jsonArray
 };
```

where, `jsonArray` would be in the following form from `getProductDetails` :

```
jsonArray.push({
    "productName": products[index].productName,
    "quantity": purchasesArray[productID]
});
```

Comment: You say "I am using the retrieved values from one collection to query another" but the code includes only one query per item in the array `purchasesArray`. So which is it, one query or two?

Comment: Or, reading it another way, is `purchasesArray` the result of a query that is not shown in the code?

Comment: @Roamer-18888, thanks for looking into my question. Your guess is right. `purchasesArray` is indeed the result of the previous query. I removed the earlier query to avoid confusion.

Comment: So, is my answer anywhere close. Don't worry about telling if it's miles out, I'll just delete it.

Comment: Your answer has significantly helped me in sending a JSON response. Please check my updated post for few of my final queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the assumption that `purchasesArray` is the result of an earlier query, it would appear that you are trying to :

- query your database once per `purchasesArray` item,
- form an array of objects, each containing data derived from the query AND the original `purchasesArray` item.

If so, and with few other guesses, then the following pattern should do the job :

```js
var getProductDetails = function() {
    // map purchasesArray to an array of promises
    var promises = purchasesArray.map(function(item) {
        return Product.findOne({
            asin: item.productID // some property of the desired item
        }).exec()
        .then(function product {
            // Here you can freely compose an object comprising data from :
            // * the synchronously derived `item` (an element of 'purchasesArray`)
            // * the asynchronously derived `product` (from database).
            // `item` is still available thanks to "closure".
            // For example :
            return {
                'productName': product.name,
                'quantity': item.quantity,
                'unitPrice': product.unitPrice
            };
        })
        // Here, by catching, no individual error will cause the whole response to fail.
        .then(null, (err) => null); 
    });
    return Promise.all(promises); // return a promise that settles when all `promises` are fulfilled or any one of them fails.
};

getProductDetails().then(results => {
    console.log(results); // `results` is an array of the objects composed in getProductDetails(), with properties  'productName', 'quantity' etc.
    res.json({
        'message': "The action was successful",
        'products': results
    });
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.sendStatus(500); // or similar
});
```

Your final code will differ in detail, particularly in the composition of the composed object. Don't rely on my guesses.

Comment: @Roamer-18888, thank you so much for the helpful answer. In the portion where you mention I can compose an object from "item" and "product", I am trying to populate the jsonArray(similar to the form I mentioned in my update). I tried pushing the elements onto the array, but  later realized that this would have to be an object. When I try composing an object with appropriate properties, I am unable to do so because of a warning of "expecting newline or semicolon". I am sorry if my query is rather silly. I am new to Node.js and promises with JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for elucidating the usage of `results`. I understood that `results` is essentially equating to the usage of  `jsonArray`. Please help me in resolving the composing of the object. You have illustrated an example with properties such as `productName`, `quantity`, and `unitPrice` . I notice a warning in my editor that does not allow me to pass properties. I get the error *expecting newline or semicolon* .  I am unable to compose it the way you described for `productName : product.productName` and `quantity : jsonArray[item]`

Comment: I realized that `jsonArray` should have been renamed to something else. I have understood the usage of `results`. Currently, with your code example of comprising data from synchronously and asynchronously derived members, I am unable to compose the object in the callback.

Comment: OK, sorry, I understand now. The syntax error is of my making. I'll edit.

Comment: Deleting comment above. I was trying to tell you stuff you already know.

Comment: And I'll change `jsonArray` back to `results`.

Comment: thank you so much for helping me with this issue. As a beginner, I have been trying to resolve it from the past couple of days. I really appreciate your excellent answer and, and wish I could give you a bonus. Out of curiosity, I wanted to seek your confirmation on my understanding - the DB query is done within a promise, which is returned after its completion. I did not quite understand the usage of `product => ` and `return Promise.all(promises)`. Are they for iterating through each product and returning all promises(associated with each item), respectively?

Comment: Answering these questions requires more than I can manage in a comment, so I'll give you a couple of references: [Arrow functions (scroll to nearly bottom of the page)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions); [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).